# Leap Year with termcal

Tags: termcal

I am using termcal to create schedules of courses in my syllabi, but I do not know how to make the current year a leap year.

Here is the code I am using for the schedule:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{calendar}{1/8/2023}{16} 
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}

\FClass
% schedule
\caltexton{1}{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{-}}}

\caltextnext{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{-}}}

\caltextnext{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Homework 1,2 \& Lab 1,2 Due (Moved to Monday Jan 29, but no grace period after that.) }}}

\caltextnext{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Homework 3 \& Lab 3 Due}}}

\caltextnext{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Homework 4 \& Lab 4 Due}}}

\caltextnext{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Homework 5 \& Lab 5 Due}}}

\caltextnext{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Homework 6 \& Lab 6 Due }}}

\caltextnext{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Homework 7 \& Lab 7 Due }}}

\caltextnext{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Homework 8 \& Lab 8 Due }}}

\caltextnext{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Spring Recess}}}

\caltextnext{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Homework 9 \& Lab 9 Due }}}

\caltextnext{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Homework 10 \& Lab 10 Due }}}


\caltextnext{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Homework 11 \& Lab 11 Due }}}

\caltextnext{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Homework 12 \& Lab 12 Due }}}

\caltextnext{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Homework 13 \& Lab 13 Due }}}

\caltextnext{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Homework 14 \& Lab 14 Due }}}

\end{calendar}
\end{center}
```

Also, here is how I define a Friday Class in the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\FClass}{%

\skipday % Monday (no class)

\skipday % Tuesday

\skipday % Wednesday

\skipday % Thursday

\calday[Friday]{\classday} 

\skipday\skipday % weekend (no class)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Your code says 2023 but you want the year to be a leap year. Did you mean to write 2024?

Comment: Welcome. // Please upgrade your posted code by following these practical steps, making it more (re-)useable: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 . Thank you